# Discover WCF hosted by Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In the solution, 4 projects : Business, the WCFService and the WCFServiceHost (a windows service) and a client

When I work in the solution, no problem, I can discover and create the proxy in the client.

When I install the host service, I start it but impossible to discover and create the proxy from visual studio with this : net.tcp://localhost:9100/MyApplicationWcf

Any idea ?

Thanks,

update #1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyApplicationWcf.MyClassWcf">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9100/MyClassWcf"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="MyClassWcf_Tcp"
                  contract="MyApplicationWcf.MyClassWcf" />

        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  address="mex" />
      </service>       
    </services>    
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show the config file of the service? And where from are you trying to do it? net.tcp://localhost:9100/MyApplicationWcf connects you to the machine from where you are trying because of "localhost".

Comment: I'll do it, restarting from the beginning. Blank solution, add a "WCF Service Library" and "Windows Service" in the "Windows service" when I try "add service reference"anyhting in the result

Comment: See update1, the service start but impossible to discvorer from VS

Comment: when you have **netTcpBinding**, you also need **mexTcpBinding** - not mexHttpBinding ..... in order to be able to discover this service over tcp/ip

Answer (score 2):

If you want to discover the service over net.tcp, you will need to define a MEX endpoint (metadata exchange) that uses the mexTcpBinding.

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MexBehavior" >
         <serviceMetadata/>                             
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="mexBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None"></security>
      </binding>
   </netTcpBinding>       
</bindings>
<services>
   <service name="YourServiceImpl"
            behaviorConfiguration="MexBehavior">                 
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="net.tcp://localhost:9100/MyApplicationWcf/"/>
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="IYourServiceContract" />
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange"   />
   </service>
</services>
```

Do you have that??

Check out: [How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I restarted from scrach, when I host the WCF in a "Web Site > WCF Service" ... I can consume from the client. Now, trying to  host in Windows Service.

Comment: See update1, the service start but impossible to discvorer from VS